# Rename file/directory name in linux

Tags: linux, rename

How to replace the below filename(Windows supported format) with customised name through linux command line. Below is just one sample case. I have 100 plus files in my test directory, hence i need a automate way, instead of manually entering 'mv' command for everyfile.

```
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\PCAP_Storage\TROJAN_MISC_ZEUS-DERIVATIVE
to 
TROJAN_MISC_ZEUS-DERIVATIVE
```

I have tried one method, result in error

```
test@localhost:~$ rename 's/C:\Users\admin\Desktop\PCAP_Storage\//g' C:\Users\admin\Desktop\PCAP_Storage\TROJAN_MISC_ZEUS-DERIVATIVE
Substitution pattern not terminated at (user-supplied code).
```

Tried ignoring special character as well.

```
test@localhost:~$ rename 's/C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\PCAP_Storage\\/' C:\Users\admin\Desktop\PCAP_Storage\TROJAN_MISC_ZEUS-DERIVATIVE
Substitution replacement not terminated at (user-supplied code).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to delete everything up to the last backslash, you can use

```
rename 's/^.*\\//s' *
```

The problem with your attempts is that the substitution command has 3 parameters:

```
s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/FLAGS
```

Any of PATTERN, REPLACEMENT, or FLAGS can be empty, but all the slashes (or whatever delimiter you use) are required.

In

```
s/C:\Users\admin\Desktop\PCAP_Storage\//g
```

the last `\` escapes the following `/` (and `\U` turns the following string uppercase, `\a` is a "beep" audio alert, and `\D` and `\P` don't mean anything), so you have a pattern of

```
C:SERS\x07DMINDESKTOPPCAP_STORAGE/
```

and a replacement part of

```
g
```

and the last `/` is missing, causing the syntax error.

Your second attempt,

```
s/C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\PCAP_Storage\\/
```

fixes these problems. Now all backslashes are properly escaped, but the last `/` is still missing. Hence the message complaining about the missing `/` terminator for the replacement part.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. this is what expected.